# In NLP, can I work with Tokenizer API of Keras with any baseline classifier like Naive Bayes?

Tags: keras, nlp, tokenize

I'm currently working on a text classification problem. I was confused on some text vectorisation techniques.

I found out that there is a Tokenizer API in keras for word embedding that is used when working with a deep neural network model. Like following

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=my_max)
```

I was wondering whether I could work with that keras Tokenizer method in an other classifier like Naive bayes or else ? Because it's like a way to vectorize inputs for my model, such as TF-IDF technique

Thank you in advance